# removing an iframe from the dom

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm simply trying to remove an `iframe` from the DOM using a chrome extension I'm building.

This code isn't removing the `iframe`.

```
var frame = document.getElementById( "tracking" ); 
frame.parentNode.removeChild( frame );
```

My manifest file is set up correctly. I'm able to access other elements on the page like this:

```
var bg = document.getElementById( "someId" ); 
bg.parentNode.removeChild( bg );
```

Why can't I remove the `iframe`?

Comment: Is the `id="tracking"` on the iframe element itself?  Or on some element within the iframe?  What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: @jfriend00 the id is the iframe element. The error is `"Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the error:  "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null", there are several possibilities:

1. There is no element in your document with the requested id.
2. You are searching for the element BEFORE it has been loaded into the DOM by running your code too early in the document loading process.

If it's the second item, then your code either needs to be moved to the end of the body element (right before `</body>`) or you need to use one of the event notifications that tell you when the page is loaded such as `window.onload`.

If this is a Chrome extension, then I would assume there is some help in that extension framework to know when the document has finished loading.  If not, you can always use [this plain javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701)  for detecting when the document is loaded.

Comment: #2 is the winner! ;) I made a mistake and it wasn't actually loaded before I tried to find it. Thanks!